# Show dialog only once. Other calls should bring dialog to front, but otherwise not have a result

Tags: c#, multithreading, wpf

This code works, as far as I can tell, but there's something that just feels wrong about it. The intended flow is like this:

- If no dialog is showing

  - Show dialog, return result
- else

  - Move dialog into view, return no result

It sounds easy enough, but because there's a possiblity of multiple threads I have to use locking. However, because the `ShowDialog()` call is blocking, I couldn't just throw a `lock` around the whole thing, so instead my code is littered with `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` calls. It gets even more complicated due to exception handling.

```
interface IDialogService
{
    bool? ShowAuthenticationDialog();
}

class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public DialogService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    private readonly object _authenticationDialogLock = new object();
    private bool _isAuthenticationDialogShowing;
    private AuthenticationDialog _authenticationDialog;

    public bool? ShowAuthenticationDialog()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_authenticationDialogLock);
        if (!_isAuthenticationDialogShowing)
        {
            try
            {
                _isAuthenticationDialogShowing = true;
                _authenticationDialog = _serviceProvider.GetService<AuthenticationDialog>();
                Monitor.Exit(_authenticationDialogLock);

                var authenticationDialogResult = _authenticationDialog.ShowDialog();

                Monitor.Enter(_authenticationDialogLock);
                return authenticationDialogResult;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                _authenticationDialog = null;
                _isAuthenticationDialogShowing = false;

                // Need this check because an exception could come from ShowDialog()
                // where we're not locked.
                if (Monitor.IsEntered(_authenticationDialogLock))
                    Monitor.Exit(_authenticationDialogLock);
            }
        }

        _authenticationDialog.Activate();
        Monitor.Exit(_authenticationDialogLock);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can I make this less "messy" somehow? Have I missed any obvious cases where the constant grab-and-release of the lock can lead to problems?

I feel like there could be an edge case where a thread can call `Activate()` before `ShowDialog()` has been called or after it has returned, but I honestly can't think of how to protect against that specific case because `ShowDialog()` is blocking and thus has to release its lock.

Oh, and if anyone's wondering, the `GetService<>()` method on the `IServiceProvider` is an extension method that looks like this:

```
public static class ServiceProviderExtensions
{
    public static T GetService<T>(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return (T)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shout in the dark, really...

```
public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<AuthenticationDialog> DialogQueue = 
        new ConcurrentQueue<AuthenticationDialog>();
    private static volatile bool _isShowing;

    public DialogService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        DialogQueue.Enqueue(serviceProvider.GetService<AuthenticationDialog>());
    }

    public bool? ShowAuthenticationDialog()
    {
        AuthenticationDialog dialog;
        DialogQueue.TryDequeue(out dialog);

        if (dialog == null)
            return null;

        if (_isShowing)
        {
            dialog.Activate();
            return null;
        }

        _isShowing = true;
        bool? result = null;

        try
        {
            result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch 
        {}
        finally
        {
            _isShowing = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, using a concurrent collection! :) Your code as it is written won't work too well though, but I understand what you were going for, and I can probably make use of this. Some issues: On the first call, the `TryDequeue` method will remove the `AuthenticationDialog`, and all the others will get `null`, and just return. I.e., they won't get to call `Activate()`, one of my requirements. Also, this will only ever work once, because you never add another `AuthenticationDialog` back to the queue.

Comment: I have doubts it's working 100%, too, but glad if it pointed you in right direction. I did, however, test by firing off multiple delayed `Task.Run()`s using same- and new instances of dialog service. It did fire `Activate()` multiple times while messagebox was visible (wrapped default MessageBox as AuthenticationDialog). So static `ConcurrentQueue` was filled (seemingly) correct.